# Detect Russian characters with grep

Tags: regex, shell, unicode, utf-8, grep

I'm trying to detect Russian characters with grep, but what I have at the moment does not appear to be doing anything:

```
 echo "Ёё" | grep -Eo "/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u"
```

No output is returned. Is there anything I have to do to tell grep to return the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is no output because grep is looking for pattern `/yourletters/u`

try this:

```
  echo "Ёё" | grep -Eo "[А-Яа-яЁё]*"
```

test here:

```
kent$  echo "Ёё" | grep -Eo "[А-Яа-яЁё]*"
Ёё
```

Comment: Thanks! So I don't need to supply the /u modifier?

Comment: glad to know about the /u modifier.. what does it mean? I didn't find it in grep man page...

Comment: Well, in PHP it means that pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. I guess this is a default with grep? (since it does correctly output)

Comment: 1, you didn't tag the question as php. 2. I know nothing (almost) about php... :(    If you want it to work with grep, you don't need it I guess.

Comment: I know, I simply was porting it to grep, thinking that I'd need to add the /u modifier also. It's not a PHP question. Thx.

Comment: use `locale -a` to find out which locales are available. Use one with utf8 :    `echo "...." | LC_ALL=thelocaleyouwant grep -Eo "......"`

Comment: You can use grep -f pattern.txt. Put your pattern to pattern.txt. This works with cyrillic.